# ERROR: (bq) Unable to create private file [/home/airflow/.config/gcloud/credentials.db]

Tags: docker, google-bigquery, airflow

I am trying to deploy some DAGs onto my local environment with docker.

I've acquired a Google Application Default Credentials and made sure it's mounted.
When going into Airflow UI there's no error shown, but when I run a DAG the tasks involving BashOperator (specifically the bq command-line tool) will always fail with the following error in the log

```
ERROR: (bq) Unable to create private file [/home/airflow/.config/gcloud/credentials.db]: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/home/airflow/.config/gcloud/credentials.db'
```

When I deploy the same python file containing the DAGs onto Cloud Composer, it worked fine without any issue.

Can you guys help me figure out what's going on here and how can I get the tasks running? Much thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check the service account inside each container.
`gcloud config list` and `gcloud auth list`

Check BQ permissions for that service account.

Answer (score 0):

I had a simillar issue - you need to ensure the user that runs the shell commands on your local machine has permission/own this file.

I solved it by adding the following command to the Docker file:

```
sudo chown -R airflow:airflow /home/airflow/.config/gcloud
```